# How to add tab index for tabPages in winform?

Tags: winforms, tabs

[image: 1]
While pressing tab key the focus is getting moved through the tab control and the button but not going into the tabpages (tabPage1 and tabPage3)

Comment: Once you tab to the tab control, you can use your arrow keys to change the tab you are on.  Without any modifications, using the tab key will only select the currently selected tab once it gets to the parent tab control.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the fact that you can move between tabpages using arrow keys, Tab key is probably not intended to be used for this, but if you really want to get it to work this way then you should add a KeyDown event

```
if (e.KeyCode = Keys.Tab)
{
  //logic which changes TabControl.SelectedIndex. If SelectedIndex equals max then select the next control
}
```